# Doctrine, QueryBuilder : use particular "where" with parenthesis

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I got a problem to make a "simple" query with the Doctrine QueryBuilder.
I try to get some "persons" which are on 10 km max.

My query :

```
    $QB = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');
    $QB->add('select', 'p')
            ->add('from', 'MyProject\Bundle\FrontBundle\Entity\Pro p')
            ->where('p.job = :job')
            ->andWhere('(3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((:latitude - abs(pro.latitude)) * pi()/180 / 2),2) + COS(:latitude * pi()/180 ) * COS(abs(pro.latitude) *  pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((:longitude - pro.longitude) *  pi()/180 / 2), 2) ))) <= 10')
            ->addOrderBy('p.dateCreation', 'DESC')
            ->addOrderBy('p.id', 'DESC')
            ->setParameter('latitude', $latitude)
            ->setParameter('longitude', $longitude)
            ->setParameter('job', $jobId);
```

The problem is on the second 'where' statement, Doctrine fails on "ASIN" because of the parenthesis that follows. It tries to execute the function...
Is there a way to escape it ? Or another way to construct this condition ?

Thanks for Doctrine professional ;)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can either write a raw SQL query for that, or implement the function ASIN(or any other) in doctrine.

Here you have a bundle that might help:

https://github.com/wiredmedia/doctrine-extensions

You can use its implementation of ASIN function:

https://github.com/wiredmedia/doctrine-extensions/blob/master/lib/DoctrineExtensions/Query/Mysql/Asin.php

And and article about custom DQL functions:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html

Comment: As I said(or wrote), you just have to add the mentioned bundle to your project, all those DQL functions are already implemented there as listed in https://github.com/wiredmedia/doctrine-extensions#including-doctrineextensions